# What does "and no difference in stability would refute both" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does "and no difference in stability would refute both" mean? Does it mean "A stability without any difference would refute both."?

> Thus, decreasing population stability with decreasing ROMPA would
> support Lidicker's hypothesis, increasing population stability would
> support Ostfeld's hypothesis, **and no difference in stability would
> refute both**.

Comment: Both Lidicker  and Ostfeld hypothesize that population stability correlates with ROMPA (one guy thinks the two metrics change "in lockstep", the other thinks they're *inversely* correlated). So if ROMPA changes but population stability remains constant, obviously that proves they're *both* mistaken. But of course, even if the two metrics *do* both change, that doesn't prove they're correlated. It might be  just coincidence.

Comment: ...unless we want to go for the "perverse" interpretation - that ***It is impossible** that there could be some specific kind of "difference in stability" which would prove that both these hypotheses are wrong*. Which is syntactically valid - it's just semantically / pragmatically unlikely.

Comment: Thank you so much @FumbleFingers for your time and your detailed description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understood from the passage was that Lidicker and Ostfeld had different hypotheses as to what would occur to the "population stability" if "ROMPA" decreased (I really don't know what any of these terms mean!)

Lidicker hypothesized that the "population stability" would decrease, while Ostfeld thought it would increase.

So if "ROMPA" decreased but the "population stability" did not change at all, both Lidicker and Ostfeld would be refuted.

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Thank you @EdmondKirsch for the answer.

Comment: @MostafaAhmadi My pleasure!